# Is it possible to use QTVR files inside of native iPad apps?

Tags: android, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I have a client who wants to have a 360 photographic view of their retail shop and allow users to click on particular objects to learn more about them (having pop-ups).  I don't want to use the browser and would like all of this within an iPad app and an Android app.  Everything I have read on SO is related to displaying on iPad Safari browser so am a little stuck.  If anyone knows a good solution it would be appreciated if you could let me know.  My client is asking me what file type they need to provide me for the photographic view.

Will I need to use something like OpenGL or Cocos2d to make this all work?

Answer (score 0):

Export the 360 panorma as a single image, depending on the size, split that into several smaller pieces. Align the images side by side and use the user's input to pan the images.

Now you don't have to map 3D points, just use 2d points for clickable points of interest.